# getting the data of a ordered list and setting into a select jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this :

```
<ol class="list">
      <li id="1">One</li>
      <li id="2">Two</li>
      <li id="3">Three</li>
</ol>
<select id="npip"></select>
```

And I want to get all the datas from each `<li>` (id and text) and set them into a select component. I mean, I want to get something like this:

```
<select id="npip">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I got a solution like this from **Arvilis M**

```
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
   $("#npip").append(new Option($(value).html(), $(value).prop("id"))); 
    alert($("#npip option").val());
});
```

But this just give me the text of each `<li>` into the option text of the select, but I also need the id of each `<li>` as value of each option. I tryed this:

```
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
   $("#npip").append(new Option($(value).html(),$(value).attr("value",value.id))); 
    alert($("#npip option").val());
});
```

With this I just get the default value 0. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have from Arvilis is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mgokrj1s/. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't get the value of each option with this code

Comment: It's there though. If you check the DOM of the jsFiddle I linked to you can see it. Why do you believe it's not there?

Comment: I tested in the console and with alert and I don't get it. But anyway, now I solved with the solution from @Adil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value.id` as value represents the `li` element and its `id` property could be used. You are alerting the val() of select. Which will always give the selected item of select. As the selection of select is not change during each loop you get 1 for all iterations.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h5fuabd1/)

```
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
   $("#npip").append(new Option($(value).html(), value.id));        
});
```

To check what you have for each option iterate through it.

```
$("#npip option").each(function(key, value){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```